# Writing a RDD to a csv

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD which is of the form

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])]
```

I want to write this into a csv file. Please suggest me how this can be done.

Doing myrdd.saveAsTextFile on gives the output as below.

```
(875,[Ljava.lang.String;@53620618)
(875,[Ljava.lang.String;@487e3c6c)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try:

```
myrdd.map(a => a._1 + "," + a._2.mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile
```

Comment: @Szymon...Thanks it works !! The output contains brackets at the start and end. Isn't it possible to get rod of those ?

Comment: Possible, I changed the response.

Comment: @Szymon...Will this solution work if my data type changes to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Array[String], Option[Array[String]]))]. It seems not to be working on the Option part, its still printing the object

Comment: @Daniel....Thanks !!! I have also used the same. Can you comment something on writing the Option types to csv.

Comment: @KundanKumar If there is option, try:
    myrdd.map(a => a._1 + "," + a._2.map(_.mkString(",")).getOrElse("None")).saveAsTextFile

Answer (score 7):

The other answer doesn't cater for escaping. Perhaps this more general solution?

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter
import java.io.StringWriter
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val toCsv = (a: Array[String]) => {
  val buf = new StringWriter
  val writer = new CSVWriter(buf)
  writer.writeAll(List(a))
  buf.toString.trim
}
rdd.map(t => Array(t._1) ++ t._2)
   .map(a => toCsv(a))
   .saveAsTextFile(dest)
```

Comment: exercise for reader: write toCsv so it does the whole partition in one go using ```mapPartition```