# How to export the output of apache spark program into a csv or text file when using Spark on Amazon EMR

Tags: apache-spark, svm

I would like to know how we can print the output after running a SVM algorithm to a csv file. I am hosting my spark cluster on AWS EMR. So any files I access are to be saved and accessed from S3 only. So when I use the saveAsTextFile command and specify an aws path, I don't see the output file(s) being stored in S3. Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a RDD to a csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294914/writing-a-rdd-to-a-csv)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spark "saveAsTextFile" action to write the results to a file.

An example is available [Here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/11/30/spark-write-to-csv-file/)

Comment: I am hosting my spark cluster on AWS EMR. So any files I access are to be saved and accessed from S3 only. So when I use the saveAsTextFile command and specify an aws path, I don't see the output file(s) being stored in S3. Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: I am using Spark on EMR because I had trouble installing Spark standalone. You have any instructions or a blog post that I can use to install Spark?

Comment: You need to do something like  RDDName.saveAsTextFile("s3://bucket name/file name")