# Writing an RDD to a CSV File

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a relatively small RDD of the format `RDD[(Int, Double)]` which I was hoping to write to a csv file. Following the logic at [Writing a RDD to a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294914/writing-a-rdd-to-a-csv), I ended up with the below code:

```
val myRdd.map{case(a, b) =>
  var line = a.toString + "," + b.toString
  line
}.saveAsTextFile
```

However, I'm receiving the below error:

```
Main.scala:111: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method saveAsTextFile in class RDD of type (path: String, codec: Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec])Unit
[error] and  method saveAsTextFile in class RDD of type (path: String)Unit
[error] match expected type ?
[error]   }.saveAsTextFile
[error]     ^
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must provide path:

```
val myRdd.map{case(a, b) =>
  var line = a.toString + "," + b.toString
  line
}.saveAsTextFile("path");
```

Both local and HDFS paths are correct. [Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@saveAsTextFile(path:String):Unit) is documentation

Comment: Yes - that answer from linked question contains error

Comment: Providing the path resolved the issue - appreciate the suggestion.